# How to open links in Phonegap application without opening device browser?

Tags: cordova

I am implementing a simple Phonegap wrapper for my web application. Basically I just need an app that is like a browser displaying fetched pages from the server. I have overwritten the `index.html` file of the Phonegap project like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

   <body onload="onBodyLoad()">

   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       function onBodyLoad()
       {
           document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
           window.location.href = window.open("http://localhost:8000/", '_self ', 'location=yes');
       }

       function onDeviceReady()
       {
           // do your thing!
       }
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

This opens the homepage of my website and displays it as the initial page for the app. And it works. The problem is that all links on that home page would open in the device browser. I would like to open them in the same Cordova webview.

Comment: This is not the purpose of hybrid mobile applications. better make mobile site instead of hybrid app.

Comment: This is a requirement, I need this kind of wrapper to have a mobile app not a mobile website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [inAppBrowser plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser). Let's read the official documentation and you'll get what you need.

Comment: I did try with that plugin. But it keeps opening the device browser. Anyways why isn't it possible to open any other internal website pages (localhost:8000/*) inside the Cordova webview. The home page opens perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need whitelist your website url in `config.xml`

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/index.html

Comment: Thanks, but this solves another issue, which I actually also encountered. Whitelisting allows navigating links. And thats nice, I am now able to navigate to the link destination BUT in a device browser. I want it to just open in the same app view.

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired result with the following code:

```
function onBodyLoad() 
{
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady()
{
    window.open("http://localhost:8000/", '_blank','toolbar=no,location=no');
}
```